# to put the value of two select tag in a <output>, html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two select tag, and I want that when a user chose one value in each of the select tag  to have an output that shows both the values:

For example if in the first tag someone choose `cars` and in the seccon `golf`,
I want to have in the output the expression `cars,golf`..How can I do this? Please help me

Comment: can you show us what u have tried so far?

Comment: can you post your code on a http://jsfiddle.net/ for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ds345/6nHS5/) in pure JavaScript.

The solution I have proposed is to capture the `onchange` event and display it in a div tag using `innerHTML`.

HTML:

```
<select id="select1">
   <option> cars </option>
   <option> bikes </option>
</select>
<div id="output"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("select1").onchange=function(){
    var e = document.getElementById("select1");
    selected1  = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    if(selected2!="")
       document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = selected1 + ", " + selected2;

};
```

Comment: You help me so much...Thank youuuuu

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough idea , you need to refine it according to your need

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(function(){

            var sb1_val;
            var sb2_val;

             $('#sb1').on('change', function() 
             {
                sb1_val = this.value ;
             });

             $('#sb2').on('change', function()
             {
                sb2_val = this.value ;

                 console.log(sb1_val+','+sb2_val); //this will output the both
                 alert(sb1_val+','+sb2_val); //this will output the both

             });

            });


        </script>


    <select id='sb1'>
        <option value='car1'>car1</option>
        <option value='car2'>car2</option>

    </select>


    <select id='sb2'>
        <option value="golf1">golf1</option>
        <option value='golf2'>golf2</option>

    </select>
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/N786d/18/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `.change()` in jQuery.

```
$("select").change(function(){
    //output the values
    $("#my_output").val($("#s1").val() + "," + $("#s2").val());
});
```

demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D5YUv/).

Comment: @user3272713 please try to understand the code. if this fixes your problem, please mark it as accepted.